How can i remove footer branding of HDESK site
Please help me remove footer credit/brandings on my HESK site.
here is the outer inspect code
<p class="text-center">Powered by <a href="https://www.hesk.com" class="link">Help Desk Software</a> <span class="font-weight-bold">HESK</span><br>More IT firepower? Try <a href="https://www.sysaid.com/?utm_source=Hesk&amp;utm_medium=cpc&amp;utm_campaign=HeskProduct_To_HP" class="link">SysAid</a></p>

attached is the screen shot of the the brandings 
This is the site Click to view
I have checked in the public directory but did not see footer.php or its equivalent or somwhere where i can locate the bandings. This is due to me being unfamiliar with the software. but with little guidance from any expert through the answer, i strongly believe that i will be able to solve this.
Thanks

I don't know anything about this, but add this CSS rule somewhere:
footer.footer {
    visibility: hidden;
}

